# Input value and event bind doesnt work in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am binding the an html input element with value bind with a viewmodel variable and an event bind with an viewmodel function variable. 
I could retrieve the value of the input in the event binded function. Code is below. 
Is there a problem while doing both together.

```
Markup
<input id="txtSearch" type="text" data-bind="value: SearchText, event:{ keyup:SearchTextChange}" style="width: 100px;" />
```

ViewmodelCode

```
    self.SearchTextChange = function () {
alert(self.SearchText());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input id="txtSearch" type="text" data-bind="value: SearchText, event:{ keyup:SearchTextChange}, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" style="width: 100px;" />
```

Value doesn't change on keyup, you only throw an alert - value changes after focus is lost by default, this changes it.

More here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html
There are more options for valueUpdate if some of those suit your case better.